# Fragmentos de código en un bloc

Tags: html

Tengo que generar una documentación de código como la que vemos en bootstrap donde se puede ver el código y se puede copiar y pegar conservando el formato. como van a ver en la imagen de ejemplo ¿Que puedo usar para hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Busate alguna clase de componente para hacer esto? no sabemos ni en que estas trabajando como para poder ayudar

Comment: Quieres que solo se muestre el codigo en ese formato con los colores cuando lo pegues en word u otro programa por ejemplo?

Comment: En este momento no tengo nada, no se por donde empezar, si wordpress, php puro o algun framework que me ayude.

Si exacto, que se pueda copiar de la pagina que voy a crear y pegar en el editor de codigo para que se pueda usar, como se hace en bootstrap o cualquier documentacion de una libreria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo una respuesta para resolver tu pregunta. Te recomiendo estas dos librerias que sirven para ese objetivo:

**1)** **highlightjs** te permitira resaltar el codigo paras su mejor visualizacion, tiene una lista amplia en diferentes lenguajes.

Este es el link: https://highlightjs.org/

CDN links: **https://cdnjs.com/libraries/highlight.js/**

Ejemplo de instalacion y uso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyJaMLkqffY

Al colocar el codigo en HTML se debe quitar los simbolo de las etiqueta <>  por < y > para que no se ejecute

**2)** **clipboardjs** Esta La otra libreria se usara para copiar el codigo fuente en la clipboard.

Links: https://clipboardjs.com/

CDN links: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/wiki/CDN-Providers

Ajunto el codigo de ejemplo para luego su explicacion:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/styles/agate.min.css">


<?php
  // usando php para cambiar simbolo de las etiqueta <>  por &lt; y &gt;
  // no se ejecuta el codigo HTML con htmlspecialchars();

   $code ='
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
                        <title>Document</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                </body>
                </html>
   ';
?>

<!-- codigo para el highlight -->
<pre>
        <code class="html" id="codigo">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $code ); ?>
        </code>
</pre>
<!-- codigo para el clipboardjs -->
<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#codigo">
    Copiar
</button>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
       hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
       new ClipboardJS('.btn');
</script>
```

Explicacion:

**1)**  Se esta usando PHP para contener el codigo de ejemplo ya que se va a enviar con el comando htmlspecialchars( $code ); el cual evitara que se ejecute el codigo HTML y no se tiene que colocar de manera manual < y &gt, si usas comilla simple recuerda emplear \' para que no cierre la cadena;

```
 <?php    
    $code ='
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
        ...';
 ?>
```

**2)** El estilo personalizado para la decoracion del codigo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/styles/agate.min.css">
```

El estilo se puede ver  por link https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/ y se consiguien en el link del CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/highlight.js/

**3)** En esta etiquetas es que se  ejemplo HTML dentro de `<code>`

```
<!-- codigo para el highlight -->
<pre>
        <code class="html" id="codigo">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $code ); ?>
        </code>
</pre>
```

**4)** El boton para copiar el contenido del cuerpo de etiqueta `<code>`

```
<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#codigo">
    Copiar
</button>
```

**5)** Carga y ejecucion de las librerias **highlight** y **clipboard**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
       hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
       new ClipboardJS('.btn');
</script>
```

Este es el resultado del codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es utilizar markdown y buscarte una librería para eso ya que markdown permite el código, te dará el formato de casi cualquier lenguaje de programación github y muchas plataformas lo utilizan.

[Para referencia de markdown](https://markdown.es/)